# How to create a 2 column list that can be extended and edited

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

How can I create a 2 column list for X (unknown) amounts of rows? I need to be able to extend/append the list and edit single entries afterward.

```
def get_types(sequence_list):
    seq_types = [[], []]

    for sequence in sequence_list:
        if sequence.seq_type not in seq_types:
            seq_types.append(sequence.seq_type)
        elif sequence.seq_type in seq_types:
            seq_index = seq_types.index(sequence.seq_type)
            # now do +1 on a second column of that seq_index

    return seq_types
```

I could probably do this with two separate lists and zip() them afterward but that feels somewhat wrong.

Comment: It's hard to follow what's going on here. Could you give us an example of what the input and output to this function look like?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, so sequence.seq_type will be a string, and the if basically checks if that string already exists in the list. If it does not exist it will append that string to the list. If it already exists it will take the second column of that already existing string and add +1 to the "counter" column.

Comment: That way I am trying to "analyze" the number of "duplicate" entries in a file.

Comment: Based on what your function does, it *seems* that you really want to use a dictionary whose keys are the `seq_types` and whose values default to `1` and get incremented each time they're discovered.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/174780). It looks like you're trying to count the number of sequences for each sequence type, for which you should use a dictionary where the keys are `sequence.seq_type` and values are the count for that type, instead of two lists. Or, use `collections.Counter` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item

Comment: A dictionary looks amazing for what I am trying to achieve :)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
def dupe_count(sequence_list):
    rv = {}
    for s in sequence_list:
        try:
            rv[s.seq_type] += 1 
        except KeyError:
            rv[s.seq_type] = 1 
    return rv
```

You can then turn this into a list of tuples (or lists, as the case may be) by itemizing the dict that it returns.

Comment: What will the KeyError be? If there is no string with that name yet?

Comment: The `KeyError` tells you that the key is not present in the dictionary.